# Importing a module containing a Name Error

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am using a specific package manager called spack, where users define their packages in a `package.py` file that is structured as following:

```
from spack import *
#inherits the "Package" class which is provided in the installation environment of spack 
#(not imported in the spack import in line 1)
class Packagename(Package):

    #includes a variety of properties and functions with specific names that are later evaluated by the spack installer
    version('123','##hashvalue##')
    ...

    #the spack installer calls this function automatically once the evaluation of the variables is complete
    install(self):
        ...
```

Importing this file by itself causes the error

```
NameError: name 'Package' is not defined
```

The file is defined this way because it is then interpreted by and embedded in the spack installation environment. Spack has a custom interpreter that allows for the file to be defined like this in spite of containing an inherent nameerror. Normally this is no problem, since the package files are mostly only called in this context.

However, I have an installation file with a number of subfunctions that I would like to run unittests on. I want to be able to import this file, create an instance of the `Packagename` class and call the functions within this class using mock parameters. I thought this could be possible by modifying the `__bases__` parameter of this class, however since I cannot even import this module in the first place I am not sure how I am supposed to gain access to the functions I have defined inside of `Packagename`.

Comment: Can you ensure that the object `Package` exists in spack module? Try in shell "from spack import Package" and see the results. If it fails, it is beacuse it doesn't exists in spack or is in another path.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi `Package` does not exist in the spack module, which is why importing this module without the context of the spack environment causes a NameError to occur here. Spack uses a custom way to interpret this module and my goal is to just gain access to those functions, e.g. by emulating this process.